# How to slice pandas column with index list?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm try extract the first two words from a string in dataframe

df["Name"]

```
     Name                            
     Anthony Frank Hawk               
     John Rodney Mullen               
     Robert Dean Silva Burnquis
     Geoffrey Joseph Rowley
```

To get index of the second " "(Space) I try this but find return NaN instead return number of characters until second Space.

```
df["temp"] = df["Name"].str.find(" ")+1
df["temp"] = df["Status"].str.find(" ", start=df["Status"], end=None)
df["temp"]
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
```

and the last step is slice those names, I try this code but don't work to.

```
df["Status"] = df["Status"].str.slice(0,df["temp"])
df["Status"]
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN

expected return

0   Anthony Frank
1   John Rodney
2   Robert Dean
3   Geoffrey Joseph
```

if you have a more efficient way to do this please let me know!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['temp'] = df.Name.str.rpartition().get(0)
df
```

**Output**

```
    Name                        temp
0   Anthony Frank Hawk          Anthony Frank
1   John Rodney Mullen          John Rodney
2   Robert Dean Silva Burnquis  Robert Dean Silva
3   Geoffrey Joseph Rowley      Geoffrey Joseph
```

**EDIT**

If only first two elements are required in output.

```
df['temp'] = df.Name.str.split().str[:2].str.join(' ')
df
```

**OR**

```
df['temp'] = df.Name.str.split().apply(lambda x:' '.join(x[:2]))
df
```

**OR**

```
df['temp'] = df.Name.str.split().apply(lambda x:' '.join([x[0], x[1]]))
df
```

**Output**

```
    Name                        temp
0   Anthony Frank Hawk          Anthony Frank
1   John Rodney Mullen          John Rodney
2   Robert Dean Silva Burnquis  Robert Dean
3   Geoffrey Joseph Rowley      Geoffrey Joseph
```

Comment: If the name have more than 3 names this don't work

Like "Robert Dean Silva Burnquis" will return "Robert Dean Silva"

Comment: Edited the answer for fetching only first two elements from the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.index(substring) instead of str.find, it returns the smallest index of the substring(such as " ", empty space) found in the string. Then you can split the string by that index and reapply the above to the second string in the resulting list.